# Prove a fact about the image of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x) = x + (1-x)\cdot \sin^2(x)$. Prove that $x\le f(x) \le 1$ for all $0<x<1$.

I tried taking the derivative of $f(x)$ but it was relatively complicated so I guess that was not the intention of the question and there is another way that I currently don't see.

What is it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\leq f(x)\iff x\leq x+(1-x)\sin^2(x)\iff 0\leq (1-x)\sin^2(x)$$
Now, $\sin^2(x)=\bigr({\sin(x)}\bigl)^2$ and the square of any real number is non-negative, so  $0\leq \sin^2(x)$, and also $0\leq 1-x$ for any $0<x<1$ of course.

---

$$f(x)\leq 1\iff x+(1-x)\sin^2(x)\leq 1\iff(1-x)\sin^2(x)\leq (1-x)\iff \sin^2(x)\leq 1$$
(where in the last step, we divided by the positive number $1-x$; if we'd divided by a negative number we'd have had to switch $\leq$ with $\geq$).

We know that $-1\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$ for any real number $x$ (look at the graph of $\sin(x)$), so that $\sin^2(x)\leq 1$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Note that $0 \lt \sin^2(x) \lt 1$ for $0 \lt x \lt 1$  Use the left side for the left side of what you want to prove, and the right for the right.